# Return All documents from collection but add a key to those satisfying the query

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation

I am a newbie to MongoDB.

I wanted to know if something like this can be achieved?

```
users Collection : 

    [
      {
        name : "John",
        Gender : "Male",
      },
      {
        name : "Alex",
        Gender : "Male",
      },
      {
        name : "Eva",
        Gender : "Female",
      }
    ]
    db.users.find({Gender : "Male"});

    Response :

    [
      {
        name : "John",
        Gender : "Male",
        isMatchingQuery : true,
      },
      {
        name : "Alex",
        Gender : "Male",
        isMatchingQuery : true,
      },
      {
        name : "Eva",
        Gender : "Female",
        isMatchingQuery : false,
      }
    ]
```

Can we get something like this where every document is return in response but the ones satisfying the query has a key added with value true and others not satisfying as false. Is it possible through aggregate?

Comment: It's not possible. but you can add this extra field(isMatchingQuery : true Or isMatchingQuery : false) after finding the documents programmatically

Comment: @TalhaNoyon As Montgomery Watts correctly pointed out, it is very much possible.

Answer (score 1):

**Please use this in one line:**

```
db.users.aggregate([{$set:{"isMatchingQuery":{$eq:["$Gender","Male"]}}}])
```

checkout the [playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/8acvYSx5nOp)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this is possible with the [aggregation framework](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/).

It would look like this:

```
db.users.aggregate([
  {
    $set: { "isMatchingQuery": { $eq: [ "$Gender", "Male" ] } }
  }
])
```

Comment: For completeness: The query part is missing ;)

Comment: A $match is not included because Belal wants to include documents that don't match the query.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone for helping out. Interestingly while digging more I found another way this can be done. Kind of a hack.

```
db.users
    .aggregate([
      {
        $project: {
          _id: 1,
          isMatchingQuery: {$eq: ["$Gender", "Male"] },
          name: 1,
        },
      },
    ])
```

Does the work for both $set and $project at once, for someone if they want only specific keys in the response.